# How to set custom type/format in controller's response_to?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, controller, format, mime

### Environment

- Rails 3.2.6
- Ruby 1.9.3p194

### What I found

```
class ThemesController < ApplicationController
  def show
  end
end
```

This setting will always render the `/views/themes/show.html.erb` page no matter what URL extension is. For example:

```
http://localhost/themes/1.json
http://localhost/themes/1.xxx
http://localhost/themes/1.custom_ext
...
```

### Encounter

I want to run `render :json=>@theme` when extension is `json`, otherwise, render the `show.html.erb` page, so I changed my code:

```
respond_to do |format|
  format.json { render :json => @theme}
  format.any {render}
end
```

It will correctly run `render :json=>@theme` when URL extension is  `.json`, and render `show.html.erb` in `.xml`, `.html`, etc.

However, I got `406 Not Acceptable` in `.xxx`, `.ooo`, `.custom_ext`, and I found it is because only supported MIME type were allowed.

### Temporary solution

```
class ThemesController < ApplicationController
  def show
    if params[:format].present? && params[:format] == "json"
      render :json => @theme
    end
  end
end
```

It works fine, and when serving more then 2 formats, such as `.xml`, `.json`, `.yaml`, etc:

```
class ThemesController < ApplicationController
  def show
    case params[:format]
    when "json" then render :json => @theme
    when "xml" then render :xml => @theme
    ...
    else render
    end
  end
end
```

It looks clean and not worse than `respond_to` style :D

### Question

1. I am wondering if there is another better solution?
2. If `case` statement can do every thing `respond_to` can do while `respond_to` can't, why should I use `respond_to`?

Answer (score 2):

Quite useful stuff, as it is usually happens, can be found in [API docs](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionController/Renderers.html#method-c-add).

Pay attention to the note there: *Note that we used Mime::CSV for the csv mime type as it comes with Rails. For a custom renderer, you’ll need to register a mime type with Mime::Type.register.*

You have to put this stuff in config/initializers/mime_types.rb. You'll find there few examples of registering non-default types.

Predefined types are [here](https://github.com/lifo/docrails/blob/master/actionpack/lib/action_dispatch/http/mime_types.rb).